# Rational Functional Tester wait for object existence

Tags: testing, rft

I'm currently modifying a Java script in Rational Functional Tester and I'm trying to tell RFT to wait for an object with a specified set of properties to appear. Specifically, I want to wait until a table with X number of rows appear. The only way I have been able to do it so far is to add a verification point that just verifies that the table has X number of rows, but I have not been able to utilize the wait for object type of VP, so this seems a little bit hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Jeff

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a built-in waitForProperty() type of method, so you cannot do something simple like tableObject.waitForProperty("rowCount", x);

Your options are to use a verification point as you already are doing (if it ain't broke...) or to roll your own synchronization point using a do/while loop and the find() method.

The `find()` codesample below assumes that `doc` is an html document.  Adjust this to be your parent java window.

```
TestObject[] tables = doc.find(atDescendant(".rowCount", x), false);
```

If you are not familiar with `find()`, do a search in the RFT API reference in the help menu.  `find()` will be your best friend in RFT scripting.

Comment: to save you time, it's on this page:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.test.ft.help/com/rational/test/ft/script/RationalTestScript.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.... you can try getting the particular property and check that you are getting the desired value of that. If not then iterate in a IF loop.

```
while (!flag) {
  if (obj.getproperty(".text").equals("Desired Text")) {
    flag = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
getobject.gettext();
```